# Should I store assets path in static variable?

Tags: flutter

For example, I want to get Image `logo.gif`

```
Image.asset('images/logo.gif')
```

Should I do it like above or create new file to store static constant like below?

In `assets_path.dart`

```
class imagePath {
  static const imageFolder = 'assets/images/';
  static const logo = imageFolder + 'logo.gif';
  //...and others images path
}
```

When use

```
import './assets_path.dart';
Image.asset(imagePath.logo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!! Highly recommended as literal strings are easy to mispell. So if you have multiple occurrences of the same file, the chances to accidentally mess up increases, so just create a `static const` variable inside a class called something like `AppAssets` for all file paths of all assets used in the application.
I do this for my apps. Also nothing is preventing you from doing the same for colors and styles, like `AppColors` and `AppStyles`

Answer (score 1):

If you need that asset path in several places, then yes, it is a good idea to store that information in one place and use the symbolic name wherever needed.

Certain types of changes to the application then become much easier and safer.

I consider it generally a good idea to replace literal constants with a meaningful name.